# Why adding text into display: inline-block div breaks the whole layout?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have this html:

```
 <html>
     <head>
       <title>Test divs</title>
     </head>

     <body style = "margin: 0px;">
        <div style = "height: 50%; border: dashed; white-space: nowrap;">
            <div style = "display: -moz-inline-stack; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display:inline; background-color: Red; width: 50%; height: 50%;">asd</div><div style = "display: -moz-inline-stack; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display:inline; background-color: Green; width: 50%; height: 50%;"></div>
        </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

For some weird reason the layout becomes broken when I add any text into inner divs.
[image]
[image]

Why this happens and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Add `vertical-align:top` to your inner divs CSS

Comment: @Paulie_D - hmm, that worked, but the fun thing is that making align `bottom` or `middle` still leaves divs aligned to `top`.

Answer (score 3):

please add float:left in your first div css layout will be fixed :)

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: dear thats a best solution .

Comment: That makes inner divs to wrap in IE8 :(

Comment: maybe this css will work on IE only you can try this if works :) 
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style-ie.css"/>
<![endif]-->

Comment: Can you show me the example? I don't know what to do with this and where to paste it.

Comment: in the above code they have linked the style-ie.css that willl work only on IE browser, so you can give all the css for the IE there

Answer (score 1):

give style  float:left    for both 2 inner div

```
<html>
     <head>
       <title>Test divs</title>
     </head>

     <body style = "margin: 0px;">
        <div style = "height: 50%; border: dashed; white-space: nowrap;">
            <div style = "display: -moz-inline-stack; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; float:left; *display:inline; 

background-color: Red; width: 50%; height: 50%;">asd</div><div style = "display: -moz-inline-stack; display: inline-block; 

zoom: 1; *display:inline; background-color: Green; width: 50%; height: 50%;float:left"></div>
        </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: That makes inner divs to wrap in IE8. Is there any other solution?